# Rails Javascript and Css doesn't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

rails 4.0.1
Hi! I have a blog application and I did place in `application.css` some css file and it didn't reflect my output. And Jquery-rails is also installed in my bundle but I don't have jquery in my output

name_of_app/articles/1

```
<link href="/stylesheets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/javascripts/defaults.js"></script>
```

`/stylesheets/all.css` and `/javascripts/defaults.js` output the same file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          color: #333;
          margin: 0px;
        }

        body, p, ol, ul, td {
          font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
          font-size:   13px;
          line-height: 18px;
        }
...
```

Comment: Do you have asset pipeline enabled?

Comment: thks J.Wood. No I don't have it enable : So now i place 'config.assets.enabled = true' in comfig/application.rb in the class Application. but I have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `type='text/css'` is missing in `<link href="/stylesheets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />`

Per rails convention try to use [manifest-files-and-directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

With this you can create

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

/*
 *= require_self
...
*/

#layout/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: Thks Swapnilabnave it's works. I had `code` <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %> I tought :all was supposed to merge all my .css file

Comment: But the type='text/css' is still missing in my output <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /> is it matters?

Comment: [Rails 4.0.2 stylesheet_link_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag) says no `MIME type` attribute whereas [Rails 3.2.13 stylesheet_link_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) has `type` attribute. I guess the .css extension might be making the difference